# Check Array Condition in Parallel setting

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have an array named `known[n]` where `known[i]` can only be 0 (false) or 1 (true), and every processor has a copy of this array. I have the following code:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    if (!known[i]){
       if (condition satisfies){
           do something;
           known[i] = 1;
       }
   }
}
```

The code above will be accessed by all processors, so some processors might be done (`known[i] = 1 for all i`) earlier than others.

How could I let the finished processors stop executing the code above while let other processors finish the code?

Comment: Might want to change `for (int i; i<n; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)` ?

Comment: You might want to use a Mutex or a Semaphore for this.

Comment: If `n` is large enough to make it worthwhile you could also have each thread do `n / number of threads` of the loop.

Comment: @user1320881 In this case I would like to assume each thread has to iterate n times.